# Listing directory on a server using php

Tags: php, server, directory, cpanel

I need to list a set directories on server using a php script that is also on the server. Here is my folder structure on the server: (ftp)

[image: 1]

and this is the code that is written in listDirectory.php (I need to know what are the sub-directories of /public_html/stickers/ and how many file exist in each of those sub-directory) I know i can hard-code it but i need a dynamic approach as the files will change a lot.

```
<html>
<title>Directories</title>
<body>
    <?php
        $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/stickers/';
        echo "<p>$directory</p>";
        
        $sticker_directories =  array(scandir($directory));
        
        echo "<p>Number of subdirs at $directory :". count($sticker_directorie) . "</p>";
        
        foreach ($sticker_directories as $dir){
            $working_dir = $directory.$dir;
            echo "<p>$working_dir</p>"; 
            if (is_dir($working_dir)){
                
                echo "<p>$working_dir" . count(scandir($working_dir)) . "</p>";
            }
        }   
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the output:

```
/home/u826063014/public_html/stickers/

Number of subdirs at /home/u826063014/public_html/stickers/ :0

/home/u826063014/public_html/stickers/Array
```

Which is not the result i was expecting. what am i doing wrong?

(I'm totally new to all this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `scandir` already returns array. There's no need to use `array`.

```
$sticker_directories = scandir($directory);

// `scandir` returns both files and subdirs. So, this string is not true
echo "<p>Number of subdirs at $directory :". count($sticker_directories) . "</p>";
//                                                                    ^ s missed
```

After that all should be fine.

Comment: Thanks i should have asked it sooner spend a whole day on it... it's working now. I'll mark your respond as answer when StackOverflow allowed me. weird thing is this code was working on windows but not on server .. thanks again.